# How to open a url in a new tab without knowing the URL the moment its clicked, and not getting blocked

Tags: javascript

I want to open an URL into a new tab, but I only find out the URL i want to redirect to after the click. I know `window.open(url, "_blank")` opens the url on a new tab, the problem I'm facing is it is getting blocked by Chrome as a popup.

Being a little bit more specific, the reason I only find out the URL when the user clicks, is that I'm making a ajax request to another API, and want to redirect the user based on the answer I get from that API.

I'm not sure if it helps, but here is the application, right now its opening on the same window, and I find it a bit counter productive, so I want to open in a new tab.

http://iagowp.github.io/micToSong/

EDIT: The ajax request only happens after the user says something, so I can't do it on mouseover, or something like that, I can't dynamically change the url element before the user clicks.

Comment: that is the purpose of the popup blocker. what can you do other than not open a new window but use other means instead?

Comment: What about performing the AJAX call onmouseover, fetching the URL and then assigning it to the href attribute before the click event?

Comment: Well, I guess I forgot to mention, the button asks access to your mic, and with the mic input, it makes the ajax request, so a mouseover wouldnt wont either. I'll edit original one, but thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by what else can I do @akonsu

Comment: use the same window maybe, or a javascript popup.

Comment: right now i'm using the same window, Im trying to move away from it. a popup would still be blocked by chrome, so it doesnt really solve my problem

Comment: What about you disable the default event on the button, perform AJAX request. Once URL is received, assign it to the href attribute to a hidden anchor element and then trigger the click event on it.

Comment: @iagowp by javascript popup I mean a `div` with absolute positioning that floats over the contents. a modal dialog implemented in DOM, not in a browser window.